# Formatting tooltip X axis in Highcharts scatter chart

Tags: highcharts

[In this Highcharts](http://plnkr.co/edit/BNjjEJzHlzo96U2vtOqU?p=preview) chart I have a scatter with a tooltip that is formatted for the y axis, however I cannot find a way to format the x axis (without using HTML in the tooltip formatting). Is this possible?

```
   var settings =  
        {
         "chart": {
           "type":"scatter"
        },
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2,
        valuePrefix: '$',
        valueSuffix: ' USD'
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Female',
        color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
        data: [[161.2, 51.6], [167.5, 59.0], [159.5, 49.2], [157.0, 63.0], [155.8, 53.6],
            [170.0, 59.0], [159.1, 47.6], [166.0, 69.8], [176.2, 66.8], [160.2, 75.2],
         // ... more data
```

Comment: As far as I understand it, you are correct. But the default format has HTML anyway....so either way, you're tooltip contains HTML - what is the problem with using it in the `pointFormat` or `formatter` yourself?

Comment: the problem is that the user would enter the HTML in the application and I would use it to build the chart object; I won't define the HTML myself. If they enter the HTML, they could inject javascript.

Comment: What do you mean by 'format the x axis'? Tooltip is not connected to any axis. Anyway, you can sanitize the  user's input and get rid of js.

Comment: in the scatter tooltip there are two values, axes x and y